# Conditional update and delete based on other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table which looks like this

```
PK ITEM_CODE PK VENDOR_CODE PRIMARY_VENDOR  
   0001         11111       T
   0001         999999      T
   0002         11111       T
   0002         999999      T
   0003         11111       T
   0004         999999      T
```

Any item which has 11111 set as the vendor code needs to be updated to 99999.

Problem is, I can't have any items without a primary vendor, so I can't simply set all instances of 11111 to F or remove them.

I also have duplicates so I can't just set all 111111 to 999999, as that violates the PK.

How can I first, update all 11111 to 999999 where there is no duplicate entry, then remove 11111 for instances where there is a 99999 entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about first deleting all values of 11111 where there is a vendor 99999.  Then do the updating on values and rows.

```
delete t from replenish_vendor t
    where vendor_code = 111111 and
          exists (select 1 from replenish_vendor t2 where t2.item_code = t.item_code and t2.vendor_code = 99999);

update replenish_vendor t
    set vendor_code = 99999,
        primary_vendor = 'F'
    where vendor_code = 111111;
```

Your text suggests that you want the primary vendor to be set of `F` in this case.  The first delete might need to take into account the `primary_vendor`.

If you have any possibility of other database manipulations happening on the database, you should wrap these in a single transaction, so other transactions will not interfere with the data.

Comment: so my table I'm working with is REPLENISH_VENDOR.  Sorry to ask, but can you update your answer with the correct table name?  I don't understand where the t2 reference comes from?

Comment: If I change "delete from" to "select * from" the first part of the query returns all the rows which need to be deleted.  If I change back to "delete from" the software complains of "incorrect syntax near 't' - SQL Server 2005 Server Management Sudio V9

Comment: my mistake, missed the first t.

Comment: @todbanner . . . That was my mistake.  I added it after your comment.  I always seem to miss the table alias before the `from` in a delete.  Just one of my bad habits.